# Help me identify bike frame. Repainted, but have serial number

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, serial-number

I got this bike second hand, accordingly to the previous owner it should be a rocky mountain. He said that he repainted the bike and created new stickers for it. I couldn't find a similar rocky mountain bike online so that's why I am asking for help here.

The serial number that I got on the BB is MAX04120342.

Thanks for anyone replying.

P.S:

Former owner said that the frame should be a 2004 model when negotiating the sale. Not sure if lying for the sake of sale or this might lead me somewhere.

Update 1: Contacted Rocky Mountains on 24.07.2020, still haven't received answer we are still searching for the frame manufacturer!

[image: Bike picture]

[image: Head tube]

Comment: Unless Rocky Mountain used a different type font on older bikes I’m suspect that’s actually a Rocky Mountain. You could try emailing them with an image of your bike and ask them if it is indeed an older model info@rockymountainuk.com

Comment: To extend Dan's comment, the serial number is only useful to the manufacturer.  Take a moment to read https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number  A serial number is not a VIN.

Comment: I'm suspicious that the fork has been replaced at some point - the bike appears older than the fork, the fork appears to have at least double the travel of the rear suspension, and that's a lot of spacers under the stem.  All signs imply the Judy fork is not original.   I've never seen a spacer like that either - it might be a steerer extender instead.

Comment: Why does the front look strange, or is that only me?

Comment: @DanK The stickers are "recreated" so to say, the previous owner said he printed them out from vector graphics from what he could find on the web, so I am pretty sure they are the same font as the ones used on actual Rocky Mountains. Thanks for the provided email, I will reach to Rocky Mountain.

Comment: @Criggie I didn't knew that serial numbers can't be used to identify manufacturer. Thanks for pointing this out!
The fork might be original as owner said he thinks the frame is manufactures in 2004. Not sure if lying for the sake of sale or there is a actual model with this design.
There seems to be a steering extender, not sure.

Comment: In the picture the front wheel looks larger than the rear.  Is that just perspective, or is the front wheel actually larger?

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks No front and back wheel size is the same. Rims are different tough.

Comment: [Bikepedia](https://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/Bikes.aspx?year=2004&brand=Rocky+Mountain) has images of most Element models going back several years before 2004.  (The [Rocky Mountain archive](https://www.bikes.com/en/catalog-archive) has a gap between 1999 and 2009.)  In *all* of them going back to *at least* 1999 the bracket on the top tube for the rear suspension is not a solid triangle, and the truss connecting the down tube, the shock and the rear stays has a different shape.

Comment: @l000p a mismatched wheelset, and a possibly changed fork implies that it has been crashed and repaired.  While not a stopper, its certainly relevant.

Comment: @Criggie The wheels are purposely mismatched. The back wheel is Remerx Jumbo for it to be more durable i suppose, the front is really light weight Mavic Cross Ride with flat spokes. The frame is not misaligned, checked, so even if it was in a crash that didn't affected it. I know that the bike is not stock out of 2004, I am after the frame manufacturer.

Comment: @DavidW Yup I browsed true all RM from that era, the frame look very similar to RM element 70 from 2004-2005 the main difference is the rear shock linkage and the head tube, also the down tube is different too, my bike it is flat when it meets the seat tube.