# Identify bike maker from frame number (DAXXXX)

Tags: vintage, framebuilding, serial-number

I have a vintage lopro bike and would like to identify the frame maker, the serial stamped on bottom bracket starts with "DA" and is then 4 numeric digits,  I was told it may have been used in the Olympics/commonwealth 1988 or 90's.

[image: Bike]
[image: Before sprayed]
[image: Bare Metal]
[image: bb]
[image: fork]
[image: drop]
[image: head]

Thanks

Comment: This is basically impossible there is no central database of frame numbers or even of frame numbering schemes.

Comment: If you don’t provide a photo, this task is utterly impossible and the question will be closed. I’m sorry to be cranky, but these questions are hard even if you show a photo. Do read this: https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: Ok ill get a photo , I thought there maybe some logic to the serials didn't think they were all random , so for instance someone else might say oh yes I have a serial starting with da and 4 digits and its a xxxx,, didnt think it would be impossible

Comment: @user3129787 have a read of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number   Basically the serial number is useful to the manufacturer, and for tracking warranty by the shop.  Its useless to the user unless you know the brand AND that brand used some kind of decodeable system, which some did and some didn't.  Without knowing the brand, serials are not helpful.   BUT PLEASE post a picture - if it was an olympic bike in use at Seol, someone will recognise it.

Comment: Updated post with pics, with how it is now, how it was when I got it(multicoloured ), and bare metal, can get close ups if they help

Comment: The BB-shell says Cinelli. I'd say that if it's really a Cinelli frame, as a reputed company they'd most certainly keep a database, especially for special frames. Contact them.

Comment: Cinelli BB shells were used by lots of frame makers, so that isn’t much help. If the multi colored paint job was original you might be able to find photos indicating what country’s team it was