# I'd like to find out the year this bicycle was made, it's a Giant Boulder

Tags: identify-this-bike, serial-number

I would like to verify the year the boulder giant was built, the serial # is c41bd535.

Comment: The easiest way is to compare livery and specification with old catalogues. The serial no. alone doesn't help much.

Comment: It's possible to give a range of a few years by identifying the drivetrain components. We can do that if you add some clear, well lit pictures of the whole bike (from drive side), crank and rear derailleur area.

Comment: See "[How do I ask a good “ID My Bike” question?](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions‌​/1337/how-do-i-ask-a‌​-good-id-my-bike-que‌​stion)" for advice on how to ask a question such as this.

Comment: The serial number may help the manufacturer identify the bike, so you could call Giant. However, there's no VIN-like database of standard format bike serial #s. In some more rare cases, people can discern a pattern and make some educated guesses, e.g. some older Schwinns, maybe some Colnagos. This is not one of those times.

Answer (score 3):

Your bicycle is a

- Model   Boulder W S in *Lavender*
- Serial number: c41bd535
- Product number: 330573

However that doesn't give a year.   I found that using step 1 of https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/registration

Your next options are to complete that registration process, and to look through https://www.google.com/search?q=giant+boulder+&tbm=isch  and bicyclebluebook.com to match a photo against your bike.

For background, you may be interested in [What is the purpose of a serial number?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number)