# I can't identify my bike... Serial number ACM05F006119 20 inch bmx?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Help me identify my bike please. I have a 20 inch aluminum BMX bike with the serial number ACM05F006110   I believe from the 80s?

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number
Serial number is useless unless you know the brand already, and even then might not tell you anything.

Answer (score 1):

Serial number is quite useless, but still, a bike with a similar serial number can be seen here:
https://bikeindex.org/bikes/633505
[image]

Serial number may be similar by chance, or it may come from the same factory.

If your bike is similar to the bike depicted there, you may have got a bmx branded MCS, unlikely it is from 80s, likely to be some mass produced aluminium thing similar to a bicycle. The bike in the picture above is from 2005.
Check this models gallery:
https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/mcs/
to see if yours is similar to any of them.

Comment: Plausible, but its also possible that the same Far East factory made frames for a dozen different bike "brands"    Good find though.