# Could you please help me identify my father's bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, restoration, sturmey-archer, badge

My father left me his old bicycle and I would like to restore it.
The unique thing I know is that it comes from Switzerland and that maybe it should include a license plate.
Unfortunately I haven't found anything online. The info I can read from the bike are:

Brand: RICO PF;
Saddle: WITTKOP;
Gear: STURMEY ARCHER;
Brake: DURALCA

I posted some photos. I hope it could help. Thanks!

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: On the bottom of frame where pedals mount they usually print serial number.

Comment: @LilBro https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number   Upshot serial number is mostly useless unless you already know the brand, AND they had a system.

Comment: No later than 1975.

Comment: Sturmey Archer had a dating system for their hubs. https://colwoodwheelworks.co.uk/sturmey-archer/sturmey-archer-hub-date-markings/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rico was a bicycle manufacturer from Switzerland (Wallisellen, a town near Zurich). Rico PF means "Rico - Paul Fries".

You can check some badges on the swiss auction sites, to try to pinpoint the production year. For example:
https://www.ricardo.ch/de/a/rico-velo-rad-marken-schild-wallisellen-1070171586/ (in the description it says it is from the 60s).

Good luck with your search and please keep us updated!

Addition 1: Duralca is a brand that at the time was owned (and founded) by Jacob Caironi, a Swiss cyclist (more info in german [here](https://www.ogs-seebach.ch/p/infoseld.php?src=ogstheme2.php&id=133) ). The company Duralca (the name coming from from Duraluminium - Caironi) dissolved in 1972 so your bike is unlikely to be <s>older</s>younger than 1972.

Comment: Thank you so much @EarlGrey! You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Paolo, I don't know the make/model of your bike, but it seems clearly to be a standard design using standard components from perhaps the mid 20th century. For example Sturmy-Archer was famous for its 3-speed hub shifting system (like the one on your bike). Here's a brief history: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/sturmey-archer.html#history

What level of restoration are you aiming for?  Although there is surface rust in places (e.g. top of seat tube) the frame and fork are likely structurally sound (an experienced bike repair shop should be able to evaluate this).  Restoring it to like-new condition would be a very involved and expensive project, including repainting the frame and fork.

Restoring the bike to good working condition would take a fair amount of effort and perhaps replacement of certain items like the wheels and chainring, but would be much more approachable.  Such a project would involve removing surface rust in limited areas, taking the bike apart and replacing rusted bolts and nuts with new ones, replacing bearings, cleaning other components, etc. I'd probably do some limiting painting to protect the formerly rusty areas, blending in with existing paint.

Thus, I don't think you need an ID for the whole bike, just some advice from a bike mechanic(s) on the more gray-beard end of the maturity spectrum on e.g. types of brake shoes or bearings or cabling to use.

Comment: Agreed. However I don’t think too much work is required. Replacing the tires (+inner tubes), brake pads and cables should be enough for a start. Probably also a good idea to grease the hub and bottom bracket bearings.

Answer (score 4):

first of all thank you for your valuable information. I give you an update on my bicycle :)
I am restoring my bike and during the painting check we found this fantastic handmade logo on the seat tube. To show the logo clearly I traced it with a pen.
I haven't found anything on the internet. Do you know where can I find this image? I would like to replicate it on my bicycle.

Many thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Great progress report!  I've never seen that logo and google's not helping.   Are you trying to make a decal or similar ?

Comment: Thanks Criggie! Yes, I would like to make a decal as soon as I have more information about this logo.

Comment: TBH that sketch you've done above is an excellent start for a decal.  You don't have to replicate the original, its your bike.  What matters is it gets used and enjoyed.

Answer (score -1):

out of interest l have a ladies version of the bike 4 speed SA hub stamped made in Switzerland dated 1946. Frame ID very faded but looks like RICO. The bikes are worth fixing as mine rides like a dream.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  This doesn't really seem to add any information to help the OP identify the bike in the question.  Once you've earned some reputation you'll be able to leave comments, but you shouldn't post comments as answers.  You might want to take the [tour].