# What BMX frame did I find?

Tags: frames, bmx, price

it has HH so I'm assuming Haro the number on the bike is as follows F2W7GO586
if you can tell me what I have and what its possibly worth

Answer (score 3):

HH does imply "haro" as a brand.  A photo might help confirm that.

The serial number is useless for identification, unless you know the brand, AND that brand kept records, AND they've been published somewhere.  See [What is the purpose of a serial number?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number)

Discussions of value are considered off-topic because they change all the time, and are highly localised.

Frankly if you "found" a bike, its probably stolen and should be reported as "found" to the local police.

Comment: found as in realized what it was after sanding the million coats of paint off the frame bought the thing for 40$

Comment: also from the serial number is it safe to say this is a may of 1986 bike?

Comment: @Barbieballer No idea - you'd have to confirm it was haro and then find out if they logged their serial numbers.