# Identify this chrome dyno flat oval

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Serial number is wya9e0193 bike is chrome and says flat oval

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE! Could you post some good pictures of your bike? That would be really helpful. Serial numbers are unfortunately of no help for identifying a bike.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find out about this bike?  Simple google search on "chrome dyno flat oval"  gives a heap of results

Comment: This post has been closed as needing detail or clarity, specifically pictures. Once you upload a few, it will automatically be flagged for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in this answer [the serial number is useless for identifying a bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77683/what-bmx-frame-did-i-find/77684#77684)

If the bike uses flat oval tubing it is likely a [Dyno VFR from 2001+](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?company%5B0%5D=32&model=44&year-start=2001&year-end=2001), though it appears GT may have branded their own version of that bike.

If it's a monotube flat oval then it could be a [Dyno Bazooka](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?company%5B%5D=32&model=1782).

It's impossible to say for sure without a picture. It's also strange it's missing the branding.