# My brother gave me a bike for my son, its a Diamondback. Serial # is F5C94618, C is backwards. Can anyone help me with some more info on this

Tags: frames

My brother gave me a Diamondback for my son,  I'm guessing it's an 85' but not sure.  S# is F5C94618 (the C is backwards). Thanks for the help.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer, or what info are you looking for?     The serial number is pretty useless sorry, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872   If you can use [edit] to add a clear and well-lit photo from the right-hand side of the bike, then we can help more.

Comment: Why don't you just ask your brother?