# I have a Traveller 3. What year and where was it built?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, schwinn

I found the serial number (8H06331). I can't find any info on the bike.

What year was it built? Where was it built?

Comment: I guess it is a Schwinn Traveller 3 (or Traveller III). Can you provide some more details? Where was the serial number located? Can you post a couple of pictures of the bike?

Comment: check http://thirtythree.org/projects-unconverted/Lowrider%20Bicycle%20Restoration/Identifying%20Schwinn%20Frames.pdf as well as https://www.angelfire.com/rant/allday101/SchwinnCodes3.html

Comment: serial number is on frame near seat. I'll get pix.

Comment: Note that pictures of the bike itself are much more useful than pictures of the serial number.

Comment: thritythree is only for Chicago built bikes. Pretty sure this one is Japan.  How do I add photos?

Comment: Related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number

Comment: photo: upload them to any free service (for example https://imgbb.com/ ) and then post here the link they provide

Comment: I'm editng the "value" part of your question out.  We don't do valuations; they're considered off-topic because they change over time and are highly regional-dependent.

Comment: Here's the canonical answer on valuations, dating from 2014   https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/q/938/

Comment: I've voted to leave question open and improved grammar. While the question is not good there is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a Schwinn Traveler III

According to [bikehistory.com](https://bikehistory.org/bikes/traveler/) Schwinn used that name from 1978 to 1979
The catalog name is "Schwinn-Approved Traveler III"

1978 page
[image]

1979 page
[image]

From the 1979 catalog

> This adult-styled 32-pound X-tra Lite 10-speed bike has been engineered by Schwinn and produced by top-rated manufacturers in Japan to combine good riding performance with an attractive price
> [Bikehistory.org](https://bikehistory.org/bikes/traveler/)

According to [Sheldon Brown](https://sheldonbrown.com/chicago-schwinns.html)

> Sometime in the 1970's, the Schwinn Chicago factory was organized by the United Auto Workers union, who felt that bicycle factory workers should be paid on the same scale as automotive workers. Unfortunately, the realities of the marketplace didn't agree, and Schwinn closed the factory, transferring most production to Japan (Panasonic) and Taiwan (Giant). Schwinn also built a factory in Greenville, Mississippi, but it didn't last, and even bought a factory in Hungary, but the deal fell through, and Schwinn never imported any Hungarian bikes to the U.S.

Schwinn went back to "Schwinn Traveler" in 1980