# this is my bike i have bought and i want to know what it is? Or how old? I would appreciate it s/n AS01104299?

Tags: frames

[image: here][image: this][image: help]MY NEW BIKE NEED TO KNOW WHAT IT IS?

help me know please

Comment: Better photos of the full bike would help a lot. Right now we can’t even tell if it has road bike handlebars, gears etc. The lack of front brake is concerning. It also looks like you are missing the screw for the seatpost clamp? Am I seeing screws of the left pedal? Is it really fully screwed in? I think it doesn’t have gears, so probably an old fixie/track bike?

Comment: I don't think it was originally a fixie but I has a single cog on it now and yes the seat post clamp screw is missing

Comment: Is there anyway of finding out with the serial number?

Comment: If you had reviewed my answer at the link I gave in comments to your other question, you’d have read that there is no global database of bike serial numbers. So, there is no way to find out anything more based on the serial number alone. If you knew the manufacturer and you called them with the serial number, they *might* be able to tell you more, but they might have gone through change of ownership and lost old records, or the old records are on paper and they can’t be bothered to search, or they might have gone bankrupt, etc.

Comment: what about the geometry of a bike would that help me? And I apologise I am on a really old computer its slow!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a fixie bike I dont know what make or model and the serial number does not appear anywhere on the internet!](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81660/i-have-a-fixie-bike-i-dont-know-what-make-or-model-and-the-serial-number-does-no)

Comment: Serial numbers are fairly useless, they are not VINs.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number

Comment: @Conorweezy Can you share why you want to know the brand?  Realistically the brand  is relatively useless especially as its old.  You could call it a "Conor's Weezy"  and paint that on it if you need a name.

Comment: I want to get the original parts!

Comment: @Conorweezy do you you want to rebuild this bike in its original configuration with period-correct parts ?  That's an expensive passtime :)

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want to do !

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the photos, you have an 80s or 90s touring bike frame.

That it now has V brakes on the rear suggests it had those, or cantilever brakes.

The rake of the fork looks more 80s than 90s, and thus its probably a steel fork.

I can't see the derailleur hanger, so bike might have had an Internally Geared Hub or it might have had a claw hanger.  At the moment it looks to be single speed because I can't see  a shifter.

The handlebars are a very old style/shape, suggesting this was an upright-style of position for an older rider.

The rear mudguard is strange - it looks like the front half of a broken full guard, and will provide minimal rain protection for the rider.

Your bike has no front brake fitted but I can see pivots, so it is not set up for going fast or far or carrying a lot of weight.  I think its a commuter bike that someone has assembled from available parts, so even identifying the brand of frame won't tell you a lot.

---

I'd suggest fitting a front brake+lever that works, and give it a basic tuneup, and then just ride it.  If you're riding in wet conditions a lot, consider a set of full mudguards for front and rear.

Looks like a nice bike.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to get original parts for it thats why I wanted to know the brand :)