# I have a BMX frame and I'm trying to identify by the VIN number

Tags: frames, bmx

The VIN number is h b l y j e e 0 0 5 9 and then it goes b l – 2552 and then another part of it in dark dark 020 trying to find out what frame this is

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. please read this question. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/32872/38270

Answer (score 1):

There is no way this can be answered based on current info, sorry.

Bicycles do not have a VIN, there is no global database like there is for automobiles.  Instead it has a serial number which the manufacturer uses internally for stock control.

The serial number is only *maybe* useful if the manufacturer stuck to a system, AND that manufacturer is already known.

Instead, try posting a clean, clear and well lit **photo** of the bike from the right hand side and a second photo showing any head tube badges or logos anywhere on the bike.   We'll see what we can spot.

At the moment, all we can say is its a BMX and it might be blue.