# Can anyone help me identify this vintage bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

I have the serial number, but I’m having a hard time cracking the code.

[image]

Comment: Serial number is not so useful. Get a photo of the headbadge (front of bike) first of all, that should be a good clue if it's original.

Comment: Headbadge, like @JoeK mentioned.  Beyond that, any written details on the parts.  Such as, name or model branding on the handlebars, stem, rims, hubs, pedals, crankarm, chainring/crankset, the coaster brake.  You may not find much, but you never know.  Any additional detail in this kind of research can help with identification and possibly the vintage.

Comment: Looks like a department store bike from maybe 1970.

Comment: There is no code for most bike serial numbers.  It is not a VIN. Much more info at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/

Comment: I'll note that the stripes on the fenders seem familiar -- Sears, Western Union, or some such.