# Jc Higgins bicycle serial numbers

Tags: serial-number

502 49470
000 163 22
M O S U
This is stamp on the bottom of the crank on the frame. Can anybody decipher this model and year.

Comment: Some important reading https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C96.1166

Answer (score -1):

This is my bike frame.
It's either 53 color flow
Or 55 promotional Thunderbird..
Either the S is 1953
Or the U is 1955
Not Sure

Comment: Welcome to the site - are you answering OP's question or asking your own question?   Are you claiming to be the OP ?