# help me to find out what brand make this frame

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

i cant find what brand make this frame.. can you guys help me to find out what brand make this frame?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange. Thanks for adding a picture. I cannot discern any unique features from this image that would identify this frame. Some close up pictures of any and every area that might show a unique feature would greatly help. Things like the head tube area, the bottom bracket, seat clamp, rear dropouts, and any identifying marks, etc. are needed. And even that might not be enough. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly the serial number is only useful once you know the brand AND they kept to some kind of system.   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/

Comment: @Criggie That might be true, and it might also be that simply shoving the serial number up a search engine would provide a clear Answer, or at least a clue or two.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin it is plausible but unlikely.  I have only ever once found something useful that way, where googling "bmx  WXYZ" (as in the front of the serial number) 
 returned a rural UK police spreadsheet listing items recovered from a burglary.  That was extraordinarily unusual, but yes it might help.  People confuse a bike serial with an automotive VIN which absolutely identifies all sorts of things in a globally unique way every time.    Sadly OP hasn't been back since posting this question.

Comment: Why not tell us exactly what response your search engine gave when you shoved up the serial number?

Comment: This is a fairly generic frame.  Likely made for department-store type bikes.

Answer (score 1):

**Brand:** no idea and it doesn't really matter.

**Observations:**  The fork looks like steel due to its fine profile and high rake.

Frame has braze-ons for mudguard / fender mounts, (so its a general purpose kind of bike)  and both brake and gear cabling stops.  This leaves the inner cable exposed for part of its length.  There are no pump pegs visible or they've been removed.

Lugged construction with a threaded steerer.

A steeper head tube angle than the seatpost angle.

No fancy derailleur hanger - looks to use a generic claw that slots up the dropout.

**Curiousnessess:**

Dimpled chainstays for tyre and chainring clearance.  Relatively unusual for the period.

There appears to be something missing around the BB - the rear derailleur cable has a stop on the right-side chainstay, but its on top.  This suggests the cable runs through a "diverter" that goes above/over the BB, not underneath like more modern bikes.  May be a chromed clamp-on part removed for the painting.

**Answer** I'd say you're looking at a late 80's steel frame with a couple of modern ideas for the time.  The fork looks to be older, or at least has nothing new about it.  The fork may not be original to the frame.

---

As for brand - you can call it whatever you like.

An option is to get some decals made/cut that say "Dan's Bike" and put them on before doing the final clearcoats.    If you want, you could call it Apollo `23, or *Colonagfaux, Time Fauxlon*, or "Toyota Corolla" Be creative.

If you choose to name it something that already exists in the bike world consider copyright first.

Comment: Agreed. Judging from the uncut lugs and stamped dropouts, this was not a particularly valuable frame when new.