# What's bike do I have

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, serial-number

I can't find what kind of bike I have and I can't find the logo anywhere on the internet I've googled image and it's not on there please help me and tell me what I have thank you[image: serial number1][image: serial 2]

1. [image: logo]

Comment: Might be worth adding a photo that includes the logo?

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: Forget the number. Instead show the photos of the whole frame and any logos.

Comment: Serial numbers are not like car VINs.  So they're useless at identification unless you already know the brand.  More info at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a BMX, at least the bare frame from a BMX.

There's a 20" wheel in one photo, which has a fairly smooth tread pattern.

Same photo shows some brake mount points for the rear wheel which are under the seat stay.  These look like U brake mounts, not V brakes like a MTB.  Brakes are missing too.

The dropouts are "trackends" which are intended for a single speed drive train.

The paint pattern on the downtube has lots of bare stripes, suggesting the paint was initially removed with a flapdisk in a grinder, or perhaps an orbital sander.  Someone didn't finish the job, perhaps realising how much work it is.

There is no bottom bracket, so no cranks, chainring or pedals.  Buying the missing parts could be significant in cost, so look for a donor bike to get started with the collection.