# haro BMX bike identify what kind of yr it is

Tags: bmx

I'm trying to figure out what kinda of haro bike this is. it says b144-3 and then next to it it says 0118960001 it says fusion on the part that hold sthe handle bar thing in and on the side of bike frame says al expert 1

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  I'm afraid that serial numbers on bikes [aren't very useful](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/32872/43557); if you want to identify your bike you really need to post pictures of the frame and any badges/decals.  You might also want to read why [it's rarely useful to know exactly what model your bike is or when it was made](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/52060/43557).

Comment: Quick google for Haro Al Expert 1: https://www.bmx-catalogue.com/haro/new-school/2001/group-1-al-expert.html

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maker and the model number the best way to find the year of a BMX bike is to go to bmxmuseum.com.
In your case go to "H" select "Haro" and then select your model from the drop down.

I selected "[Group 1 AL Expert](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/search?company%5B%5D=41&model=4804)"
It came back with three versions, 1999, 2000, and 2001.
[image]
In comments DoNuT found reference to a 2001 model.
The bmx-catalogue.com site DoNuT references has a pretty complete collection of [catalog pages for Haro](https://www.bmx-catalogue.com/haro/year.html) for more details on specific years.