# Specialized bike - Can you help identify?

Tags: identify-this-bike, hydraulic-disc-brake, specialized-bikes

[![660 4th St, #107, San Francisco, CA 94107, US[image: ][1][1]]Says "Crosstrail" on it with a serial number starting with "wsbc." Also, can you give me estimated resell[image] value?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Bicycles SE. For identifying a bike, generally refer to https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question, so pictures would be very helpful as a start, also any information you already have. I think, we also don't do cost estimates because they usually don't have much "community value". However, I only found a Crosstrail Disc made in 2016: https://www.specialized.com/at/de/crosstrail-disc/p/106407?color=195730-106407 - as a guideline for resell value (depending on the condition of the bike).

Comment: The Crosstrail line seems to have been discontinued and is hardly to be found on Ebay, so your best bet on a resell value is looking up what bikes of similar spec (like a low-tier Sirrus X 2.0) are sold on various platform and go for it.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycle Stack Exchange, Kyla.  A couple things you should know that relate to your question: First is that questions regarding bicycle identification are typically not given much attention. Especially so when there are no photos to see the bike. Serial numbers are almost always unhelpful in determining a make & model of an unknown bike. I can tell you that "Crosstrail" is a model of crossover bike made by Specialized. The beginning of the SN you provide is also familiar to me as typical of Specialized serial numbers of recent years.  Valuation of bikes is considered off-topic here..

Comment: ...off-topic here due to the high number of variables involved, as well as  the subjective nature of value.  It's often said, "the (monetary) value of a bicycle is whatever someone is willing to pay."  Thus, what Mr. X might pay for it could be vastly different than what Ms. Y  would offer.   I will offer up that the Specialized Crosstrail range of models (again--variations between bikes of the same model affect value) are neither very cheap, nor are they very expensive. They are designed and marketed toward casual riders seeking a comfortable bike capable on city pavement and country lanes.

Comment: What research have you done?   https://www.google.com/search?q=Specialized+Crosstrail    shows a heap of info about different years.     As for the Serial, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/

Comment: Thank you so much guys you really know your stuff. I added a few photos does that change any of your answers? I don’t think it does but I forgot to put them up, thank you for pointing that out ;)