# Help me decode Haro Vector serial number please

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, serial-number

Recently acquired a Haro Vector mountain bike. Serial number V2K506004 anyone please help me decode this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  There is no standard for bicycle serial numbers, so they are rarely useful.  What in particular is it you need to find out?

Comment: Welcome to the site - what's your end goal here?   A bike is not like a car where there are known model years and parts have to fit the year+model.  You may be interested to read https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/ about this.

Comment: Separately, the purpose of a Serial Number is expanded on at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/ - in short a serial is unique to the manufacturer who may have had a system, maybe kept notes, and perhaps someone has that breakdown to share.  Its not at all like a car VIN which is globally unique and structured to tell you everything down to the original paint colour.

Comment: We can probably tell you something more, if you can please use [edit] to add a couple of clear well-lit photos.  One from the right hand side of the bike, and additional showing anything unique or unusual.