# Is there a way to tell if a Pinarello Dogma f10 I would like to buy is Original or not?

Tags: pinarello

I am about to buy a Pinarello f10 and I want to make sure it is authentic, or if it is not. The serial number is 8DI5500590037.

Comment: Hi, check this out... https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number/ - numbers won't help much, only good pictures of the bike, a full view and detail shots of forks and groupset components will help to make sure it is authentic.

Comment: There's no central database of bike serial numbers that consumers can search. You would be better off emailing Pinarello and asking them if they can help.

Comment: See also https://pinarello.com/europe/en/false-frames - it seems you can have the SN checked via Pinarello dealers, the F10 is a fairly recent model, so that might help together with convincing pictures to compare against an official photo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways to tell. I have built the genuine article up from a frameset before as well as a relatively convincing bootleg version.

The counterfeit version could be specified with any bottom bracket shell: British, Italian or press. British would be the preferred choice by most, probably.

The genuine F10 has an italian threaded bottom bracket shell. Other differences are less easy to spot and relate to the quality of finish both visible and internal. Pinarello also have or had a tool on their website to check the veracity of the serial number.

Comment: There's some good comparison photos at https://carbonbikerepair.co.uk/wp/?p=3947 which are similar to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Paperwork

Anyone spending that kind of money on a bike would be more likely to have the sales receipt.  Ask for it.

You can also try checking the serial number with Pinarello directly - start at  https://pinarello.com/global/en/false-frames  and try a message to support.