# Question regarding serial number

Tags: frames

Can anyone help me decipher this serial number on my DB? ACS6J02432

I am trying to figure out the exact year and model of this 24" BMX

Comment: Related: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number

Comment: From the info presented, its possibly a "diamondback" and dates from between 1970 and today.  24" BMX was a more recent thing so that moves the earliest year to about the late 90's.

Comment: BMXs are notoriously hard to date and identify because they didn't change a whole lot over time, but a photo might help.  Please use [edit] to add some clear clean and well-lit photos.