# Dyno pro compe bmx identification

Tags: identify-this-bike

I am struggling finding the exact model I have here. Can I bum someone's knowledge please and thank you.

Here are the exact numbers located underneath.

S8cto6774

9803

Comment: Hi, serial numbers are often arbitrary and for most brands, no database exists, in order to get some help, please have a look at [this](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question) guide and update the question with some pictures. That being said, the "hit rate" on BMX IDs here is relatively low....

Comment: The bmxmuseum is a great resource. Here is a link to all the dyno bikes https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/dyno/ Chances are very good that you will find your bike.

Comment: Photos are useful for ID questions, whereas serial numbers are not.  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/  expands on that.