# I need to look up a serial number for bicycle

Tags: bmx

I need to look up a serial number for a bicycle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why?   What information do you intend on finding?   Sadly, there is no "central registry" of bike serial numbers so you need to know the brand, and hope they have a recognised system.   Many BMXs don't.    For more info see  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/

Answer (score 1):

Most serial numbers are under the bicycle frame's bottom bracket.
If it's hard to read, because of the paint colour, take a photo of it with a mobile phone and then edit the photo, play with the edit option to see if any of the photo editing option help make the serial number in the image clearer.
I had to do this recently with a bicycle painted in bright red and I manage to get a good reading.
Hope this helps.