How to know model of my bike if I just know serial number Do yuo know this code for bike IF2I04753
Code Do yuo know this code for bike IF2I04753

There is nothing we can do with just a serial number - they're not like automotive VINs.  See https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/ for more info on serials.

Instead, take a clean, clear and well lit photo of your bike from the right hand side and [edit] that into your answer.   Also add a photo of any text, logos, or anything distinctive.

Does this answer your question? What is the purpose of a serial number?
