Cannondale Synapse 5 - Serial Number
Can anyone help me to identify the year of my Cannondale Synapse 5 Carbon Fiber?  The serial number starts with JMxxxxx. The information is located on the bottom of the crankset and it is believed to be a 2012-2015??  Thank you in advance for your assistance - Gary

Your best option is to contact Cannondale directly.  Serial numbers are mostly meaningless for many brands of bike.    See also https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number

Thank you for the feedback.  I found information that explains serial number information for vintage Cannondales, it’s the late model bikes that are a challenge.  Yes, I have tried calling Cannondale, I can’t seem to find a valid number.

You might try posting some pictures with details. Someone with access to annual catalogs may be able to nail down the year, but pictures are needed. Edit your question and add the photos there.

201x stuff is "vintage" already?   :sadness:

To be clear, Cannondales of this time period has a 7 digit serial number with an associated bar code on the under side of the bike's bottom bracket shell ("bottom of crankset" phrase you use may refer to this area). The Cannondale website instructs you to use a mobile app to link to manuals, register your bike, and multiple other tools to enhance your experience. This link has information about the Cannondale app and how to use your bike's serial number to connect to manuals and other tools specific to your model.
Beginning in 2015, the naming of the Synapse included the group set. For instance the "Synapse Carbon 5" (2012-2014) used Shimano's 105 groupset, and with the 2015 models, the phrase, "Synapse Carbon 105 5," is used.  Probably to help distinguish it from Synapse Carbon 5 Disc that sported a SRAM Rival groupset.
The Cannondale Bike Archive has links to the catalogs from 2012 to the present.  The catalog links to downloadable PDF files of the yearly catalog.  So, from the above website, check out the yearly road bike catalogs and compare your bike's colorway and components (like wheels, seatpost, as the Synapse Carbon 5's ran 105 grousets, exclusively, it appears, until the above mentioned SRAM option with a disc brake frame). When you've found the matching colorway of your bike to the specific year catalog, you've now learned the model year of your bike.
Keep in mind that if you bought the bike used, a previous owner may have switched components or even obtained a Frameset and built it with his/her choice of components. Comparing colorway and frame details (shape, presence and location of cable stops, type and shape of dropouts, sometimes type of bottom bracket required) to the official catalog can be the best way to narrow down or bullseye the model year of a known brand of bike.  Cannondale serial numbers also are nicely coded with information, and that process I'll let you get into. I suggest taking trial run of the Cannondale app and it's variety of tools along with your specific serial number to assist you on that venture.
