Just asking, what brand of fixed gear frame is this
Can you help me with this? I'm curious of what kind of fixed gear frame is this.

Welcome to the site - could you please use [edit] to add more details?  A couple of clear, well-lit photos would be most useful.   A serial number is not, because https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/

I see the question has been closed - if you edit it with more info, then the question will be submitted to the Reopen queue.  Please don't let Closure put you off.
